# R: determine if `suppressMessages()` has been invoked

Tags: r

R's `suppressMessages` function remains a mystery. What does it do? It does not seem to change global options. It does not appear to add anything to the env. So how does it work? I would like to create a function that detects if `suppressMessages` has been invoked. However, I don't know where to even start.

Simple example:

```r
#super basic function
myfunfction=function(x = 1){
  y = x * 2
  return(y)
}

#I can call this function as is
myfunfction(x=4)

#I can call it with suppressMessages
suppressMessages(myfunfction(x=4))
```

Is there any way for `myfunfction` to 'know' that `suppressMessages` is used?

Broader context: Long-running Rcpp functions that benefit from having status messages. `Rprintf` and `Rcpp::Rcout` are not silenced by `suppressMessages`. Being able to detect it would be helpful.

Comment: Can  you clarify please? `suppressMessages()` applies to a *particular expression*; it's not like setting `options("warn")`.  Do you want to know whether messages are being suppressed while a particular piece of code is being run? (e.g. to tell, inside the function `f()`, whether the function has been invoked via `suppressMessages(f())`?) Can you give a little more context/an example of a use case?

Comment: PS it seems as though querying the currently active condition handlers could be tricky ...

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Yes, it is tricky, and a major p in the a, especially when you want to pass that message suppression to cpp or other external functions. R's condition help file is super uninformative and lacking examples. base-R would probably fail current-day CRAN review.

Comment: I can find almost nothing in the R language def or internals document. Section 1.4 mentions https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html . I think `r-devel@lists.r-project.org` might be the best venue for this question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this:

```r
is_suppressed <- function() {
  withRestarts({
    signalCondition(structure(list(), class = c("message", "condition")))
    FALSE
  }, muffleMessage = function() TRUE)
}
```

```r
is_suppressed()
#> FALSE
suppressMessages(is_suppressed())
#> TRUE
```

It has a small side effect, though. It emits a "message" condition, every time it is called, and if some code on the stack (e.g. code calling your package/function) is catching these conditions, they might be affected.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is similar to what Ivan wrote on R-devel:
```are_messages_suppressed <- function() withRestarts(
 {
  signalCondition(simpleMessage(''))
  # we stay here if restart is not invoked
  FALSE
 },
 muffleMessage = function()
  # we jump here if restart is invoked
  TRUE
)```